# Boost::asio socket - how to make read_some 'throw' in "timeout"?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, timeout, boost-asio

So normaly we do something like this `socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer, buffer_size));` but how to make it throw an exeption in case of read has not started for some time longer than say 333 seconds?

Comment: 666 - the number of the beast.  668, his neighbour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider using `async_read_some` instead of `read_some`, since it allows you to start a new background timer simultaneously with the read. Then, to create a new timer for each new socket you do:

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;

time_t_timer timer(io_service);

timer.expires_from_now(333);
std::cout << "Starting asynchronous wait\n";
timer.async_wait(&handle_timeout);
io_service.run();
```

You will have two asyncronous calls waiting on background.

Whenever you receive some data on the timer you can reset the countdown using [cancel](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/cancel.html) and `expires_from_now`, and when the timer expires you can close the socket or take some other action.

Comment: And what if I am receiving it for more time than 333 seconds?